# Issues accessing linking/scope inside of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-services

Could use some help understanding whats happening here... I need to create a directive from within a service and add it to the DOM... check! But now when I try to access properties on the scope, inside of the directive/template I get nothing. Correction, `{{property}}` inside of the template by itself will work, but not `<h1>{{property}}</h1>`.. so in other words, it stops working when I add HTML to the template. Anyways I created this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JdoX9SzNNuFs8cvjvGKF?p=preview) to try to understand.

app:

```
  angular.module('app', [])
    .run(['fooService', function(fooService) {
      fooService.foo('Hello World!');
    }]);
```

service:

```
  function fooService($rootScope, $compile, $animate) {

    function createDirective(message) {
      var newFoo = {
        scope: $rootScope.$new()
      };

      var target = angular.element(document.querySelector('#bar'));
      var elem = angular.element(document.createElement('foo'));

      newFoo.scope.message = message;

      newFoo.elem = $compile(elem)(newFoo.scope);
      $animate.enter(newFoo.elem, target).then(function() {});
    }


    function foo(message, overrides) {
      return createDirective(message);
    }

    return {
      foo: foo
    };
  }

  fooService.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$compile', '$animate'];

  angular.module('app')
    .factory('fooService', fooService);
```

directive:

```
  function fooDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      templateUrl: 'foo.html',
      link: function(scope) {
        console.log(scope.message);
      }
    }
  }

  angular.module('app')
    .directive('foo', fooDirective);
```

template - displays: "Directive message:"

```
<h1>
  Directive message: {{message}}
</h1>
```

working template -displays: "Directive message: Hello World!"

```
Directive message: {{message}}
```

New to Angular still so please forgive me if this is not how it should be done but can someone please explain whats happening? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template needs to be compiled with with the scope as the context. Replace your directive with:

```
function fooDirective($compile, $templateRequest) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      link: function(scope, el) {
        console.log(scope.message);


        $templateRequest("foo.html").then(function(html){
          var template = angular.element(html);
          el.append(template);
          $compile(template)(scope);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Gotcha. But now I'm getting two templates rendered per directive? is that from $compile running twice (inside the directive and inside the service)? in which case I should probably do this in the service huh? since that where I'll bind everything to the scope... any ways, this answers why its not working at least to thanks. I'll mark as correct

Comment: Actually... apparently everything worked as is if I add `replace: true` lol thanks thought, still learned something